# Find checkbox and add text

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to add in the *secondary text* field at this [website](https://buffer.com/pablo) a text string.

My selenium method looks like the following:

```
public void addSecondaryText(String string) {
    //click secondary button
    WebElement secButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label/input[@id='sub-text-check']"));
    if (secButton.isDisplayed()) {
        secButton.click();          
    }
    //clear text
    WebElement secTextField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sub-text']"));
    secTextField.clear(); // I get the exception here!
    //add text
    secTextField.sendKeys(string);
}
```

However, I currently get an exception for `secTextField.clear();`, that it cannot be manipulated:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Have you tried adding waits before sending clear?

Comment: @VikasNehaOjha Just waited for `Thread.sleep(5000);`, however, I  still get the same result  as above.

Comment: You first need to make your secButton.click() working. Remove it from if condition because it is going to be displayed. After you get that working, the secTextField.clear() should work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the textarea depends on another button and you need to perform a click on it before making the textarea editable. See the image below.

```
//List will help of to determine the "Add secondary text" button needs to be clicked on not
//if the count is greater than 0 then click it
IList<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//span[contains(text(),'Add secondary text')]"));
if (elements.Count>0)
{
    elements.FirstOrDefault().Click();
}
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("sub-text"));
element.Clear();
element.SendKeys("Test");
```

[image]

Comment: He is able to find the correct element but not able to manipulate it. Because he is not being able to click the button which makes that target field displayed.

Comment: @VikasNehaOjha Correct. But, he is targeting wrong element. And, I wrote the selector such a way it will do a quick check to see if the element is toggled or not.

Comment: The element he is targeting is correct. But it is hidden and becomes visible only when another button is clicked, which he is not clicking.

Comment: Well, that's not entirely true. It's the same element(button) that affects the textarea. With the selector OP is using does not guarantee that it change the state of textarea it supposed to be. In correct state of the checkbox should return `isDisplayed()` == true

Comment: I agree. Actually I have OCD and was looking at the problem very conventionally.

Comment: @VikasNehaOjha Well, it's very easy to miss unless you carefully investigate the `html`

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work -

```
public void addSecondaryText(String string) {
    //click secondary button
    WebElement secButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='sub-text-toggle']"));
    secButton.click();

    //clear text
    WebElement secTextField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sub-text']"));
    secTextField.clear(); // I get the exception here!
    //add text
    secTextField.sendKeys(string);
}
```